# Horizontal and Vertical dilation using skimage

Tags: scikit-image, mathematical-morphology, dilation

My task is to perform directional morphological dilation on character, so it produces the horizontal bar for vertical dilation and vertical bar for horizontal dilation.
[image: ![enter image description here]

Where a) is an original character b) after vertical dilation and c) after horizontal dilation.

Below is the code for skimage however it did not produce the result i was expecting for.

```
from skimage.morphology import dilation, erosion
from skimage.io import imshow, imread, show
import numpy as np
from skimage.filters import threshold_otsu

image = imread('img/A_en.png', as_gray=True)
#binarizing the image
thresh = threshold_otsu(image)
binary = image > thresh

sev = np.ones((20,1)) #20 -row 1-column
seh = np.ones((1,20))
vertical = erosion(binary,sev)
horizontal = erosion(binary, seh)
```

Result:
[image: Original Image][image: Vertical][image: Horizontal]

Comment: Please try to improve your question, firstly by making it a *"Minimum Complete Verifiable Example"* meaning you put back all the `import` statements you have removed for some reason, and secondly by being more specific about the issue with the result - maybe you could share the results you surely must have? Thank you.

Comment: Use erosion (erode), not dilation..

Comment: I see you've corrected the example to use erosion.  Now, note that there is a vertical black bar on the right edge of your input image: that will mess with your horizontal erosion (as you can see). Other than that, the results look correct: note that a footprint of 20 is equivalent to a radius of 10, and if you look at the top of the A it appears to have moved by about 10 pixels. So you just need to increase the size of your footprint.

Answer (score 2):

Morphology treats the white area as foreground and the black area as background. So, if you want to dilate the letters, which are black, you need to either:

- invert the image first, or
- use the counterpart to dilation, which is erosion.